# How to parse each line in a file using regex and extract content before character?

Tags: python

I'm trying to parse a file and extract content right before a certain character, in this case `|`, to create a dictionary and filter out duplicates based on this content/key. My take on it is that I should use regular expression for this.

Mock input data:

```
AK_0004: abc123|Abc1231301820 abc123|Abc1231308920 qwerty|Qwerty0202470 qwerty|Qwerty209910

AK_0005: abc123|Abc12302100 abc123|Abc12302110 qwerty|Qwerty0209580 qwerty|Qwerty0209600

AK_0062: abc123|Abc12300430 qwerty|Qwerty0211140
```

I want:

```
AK_0004: abc123 abc123 qwerty qwerty
```

and so on...

My attempt so far was:

```
import re

for line in open('splittest.txt', 'r'):

    m = re.compile(r"^[^|]*")

    print re.findall(m, line)
```

output:

```
['AK_0004: abc123']

['AK_0005: abc123']

['AK_0006: abc123']
```

Comment: And you think we should write this for you because...?

Comment: People will be more inclined to help if you show you at least tried. BTW instead of regex, try using split. Might be easier.

Comment: Hi. yes of course I tried, added it as edit. This was my first post here so I was a little unsure if to include it or not. Sorry!  @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed use regexps, specifically you want create capture group with a pattern that matches the text before a `|` which I will assume is any word-character.

```
import re

# Compile the regex pattern. (\w+) is our capture group.
p = re.compile(r'(\w+)\|')

line = 'AK_0004: abc123|Abc1231301820 abc123|Abc1231308920 qwerty|Qwerty0202470 qwerty|Qwerty209910'

# Get the AK_xxx
line_id = line.split(':')[0]

# Findall matches
m = p.findall(line)

print('{}: {}'.format(line_id, ' '.join(m)))
```

Will produce:

```
AK_0004: abc123 abc123 qwerty qwerty
```

Comment: Hi @Danyule , this works like a charm, perfect! I had started a script trying to use regex. Didn't realise it was that simple using p = re.compile(r'(\w+)\|'), beautiful! If I were to discard those lines that has duplicates in the input file, do you recommend using regex there aswell?

Comment: When you say duplicates if you mean `AK_0004: abc123 abc123 qwerty qwerty` should become `AK_0004: abc123 qwerty` then a simple solution is `unique = list(set(m))`.

Comment: No, I dont't want to simply remove a duplicate and not remove duplicate lines either, instead remove those lines that contain a duplicate of for example "abc123". So in the original input file, line "AK_0004: abc123 abc123 qwerty qwerty" would be removed. @Danyule

Comment: If `len(set(m)) != len(m)` is true then you have duplicates in that line.

Comment: Ahh yes of course, that does the trick. Thank you for the help! @Danyule

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be simpler without a regular expression if you use clever splits and list comprehensions like so:

```
dicty = {}
for line in whatever:
    parts = line.split(' ')
    head = parts[0][:-1]
    stuff = [s.split('|')[0] for s in parts[1:]]
    dicty[head] = stuff
    print("{}: {}".format(head, ' '.join(stuff)))
```

or if you'd like to remove duplicates:

```
for line in whatever:
    parts = line.split(' ')
    head = parts[0][:-1]
    stuff = set([s.split('|')[0] for s in parts[1:]])
    dicty[head] = stuff
    print("{}: {}".format(head, ' '.join(stuff)))
```

Comment: Hi @Brian, this works perfect aswell as with regex, thank you! Can I use dicty to remove those lines that contains a duplicate 'stuff' in the original input file?